# Get data from local php file

Tags: angular

I am trying to get data from a php file which is inside /app folder in my project.

PHP looks like:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    $data = array(
        array('id' => '1','first_name' => 'Cynthia'),
        array('id' => '2','first_name' => 'Keith'),
        array('id' => '3','first_name' => 'Robert'),
        array('id' => '4','first_name' => 'Theresa'),
        array('id' => '5','first_name' => 'Margaret')
    );
 
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

And there is app.components.ts

```
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Injectable, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<ul>
        <li *ngFor="let person of data">
           {{person.id}} - {{person.first_name}}
        </li>
         </ul>`
})
export class AppComponent {

    private data;

    constructor(
        private http:Http
        ) {}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.getData();
    }

    getData(){
       return this.http.get('./index.php')
        .subscribe(
                data=>this.data = JSON.stringify(data),
                error =>console.log(error),
                ()=>console.log("done"));
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am getting 404 error

> GET http://localhost:4200/index.php 404 (Not Found)

How can I get data from php file locally?

Comment: Well as you said, the the file is under your app folder. When you are using a relative path: `'./index.php'` it will automatically look under localhost. You need to append the complete "url" starting from the top level folder (for you maybe `src`?). When you fix that, it still doesn't work, in the response you'll just get the actual code you have written. You'd need some server solution for that (WAMP?)

Comment: you right with path and as you predicted I have error: ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object

Comment: Yes, if you check your network tab you can see that you are getting the php code snippet instead of JSON. If you are running on windows, perhaps you could use e.g Uniform Server for your php, simple fast solution :) It should work when you set the headers in php-file like you have, just maybe need to enable cors in your browser. But it's not a big hassle during development and playing around with your code. That would be my preferred route ;)

Comment: Ok I've created wamp server and now my path is like http://localhost:8080/php/index.php but still have same error Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object
My network browser page: http://imgur.com/a/BSJBI

Comment: Okay, check your network tab, what are you receiving?

Comment: @AJT_82 edited my comment

Comment: @AJT_82 Fixed :) I changed to data.json(), instead JSON.stringify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since comments tend to go unnoticed, here's an answer gathered from our discussion:

When using a relative path like: `'./index.php'`, angular looks for this file under localhost. But you mentioned that the file is located in app-folder. So instead of providing a relative path, use the complete "url", starting from the top level, usually `src`.

When this is solved, there will still be an issue, you will not be returned JSON, but instead the php-script you have written. You need a server for your php-script. If you are running on Windows, Uniform Server is a viable option during development. Just remember to enable CORS in your php-scripts, like you have:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

and possibly you need to enable cors in your browser. [**Here is the extension for Chrome browser**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi).